# Rails.cache writes wrong ActiveStorage variant url to cache store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, rails-activestorage

I'm facing a weird issue around Rails caching and ActiveStorage url generation, apparently. Let me explain...

I've got a partial that includes an `image_tag` wrapping an ActiveStorage variant:

```
irb(main):005:0> image_tag(news_item.image.variant(resize: '1110x>'))
```

the output looks like this, quite correct:

```
<img src=\"https://www.example.com/rails/active_storage/representations/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsi ... \" />
```

However if I wrap the `image_tag` in a `cache(news_item)`, the actual fragment written to the cache store takes the pod's (I'm using kubernetes here) IP as the `:host`:

```
irb(main):008:0> Rails.cache.fetch("some_cache_key")
=> <img src=\"http://10.244.4.19:3000/rails/active_storage/representations/eyJfcm... \" />
```

Has anybody had a similar issue and found a solution?